# How to correctly redirect website from http to https without losing Google Indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, http-redirect

I have recently added SSL support for an old Rails 2.3.1 website.  I have the following code to redirect from http to https:

Application Controller:

```
  before_filter :need_ssl

protected 


  def need_ssl
    if RAILS_ENV=="production"
      redirect_to "https://#{request.host}#{request.request_uri}" unless request.ssl? 
    end
  end
```

However I got a message from Google:

```
Approximately 80% of your HTTP pages that were indexed before migration can no longer be found in either your HTTP or HTTPS site
```

I looked and found that 572 had been excluded from indexing because of the redirect.

How can I then add the correct code for redirecting so I don't lose the indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Google guidelines

Google has specific guidelines for moving a site to start using SSL

> **Use server-side 301 redirects**
>
> Redirect your users and search engines to the HTTPS page or resource with server-side 301 HTTP redirects.
>
> ...
>
> **Migrating from HTTP to HTTPS**
>
> If you migrate your site from HTTP to HTTPS, Google treats this simply as a site move with URL changes. This can temporarily affect some of your traffic numbers.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543

This counts as a site move *with URL change*

> **Site move with URL changes**
>
> The page URLs change.
>
> For example: The protocol changes — http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
>
> ...
>
> **Expect temporary fluctuation in site ranking during the move.**
>
> With any significant change to a site, you may experience ranking fluctuations while Google recrawls and reindexes your site. As a general rule, a medium-sized website can take a few weeks for most pages to move in our index; larger sites can take longer. The speed at which Googlebot and our systems discover and process moved URLs largely depends on the number of URLs and your server speed. Submitting a sitemap can help make the discovery process quicker, and it's fine to move your site in sections.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34437

### Redirecting in Ruby

So in your case you want to ensure that you use 301 redirects. By default *redirect_to* uses 302 in Ruby.

v2.3: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M001811

v5.2.1:  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

> The redirection happens as a 302 Found header unless otherwise specified using the :status option:

**Updated code for Rails 2.3**

```
redirect_to("https://#{request.host}#{request.request_uri}", :status => 301) unless request.ssl?
```

**Alternative code for Rails 3.1+**

Use *force_ssl* as specified in https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

> *config.force_ssl* forces all requests to be served over HTTPS by using the ActionDispatch::SSL middleware, and sets config.action_mailer.default_url_options to be { protocol: 'https' }.

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

### Indexing issues

But you may still experience temporary issues with indexing. To help google find your new HTTPS pages faster you should create a sitemap with your new HTTPS pages and add it to Google Search Console https://search.google.com/search-console/about.

See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668 for details of the sitemap formats that Google accepts.

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thank you @agilejoshua. I've edited my answer to make sure readers won't skip yours. By the way, could you add `config.force_ssl` part?

Comment: Thank you so very much @agilejoshua. I just saw your answer and  I decided to change the accepted answer as you put so much effort and useful information. I used config.force_ssl as suggested by H Dox, and will submit the xml sitemap to google using the new https site.

Comment: @chell note that sometimes it is easier to create a text based sitemap (one url per line) which gives you less control over how the urls are treated but is very simple to create. Rather than have to output correct xml. Bing also supports text based sitemaps.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I normally do to migrate my website to `https`.

Redirect all `http` traffic to `https` with `301 redirect` in my `nginx` configure

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myawesomewebsite.com;
    return 301   https://myawesomewebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

Enable `force_ssl` in `config/application.rb`

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

**Edit:** Thank you all for voting my answer. But please also check @agilejoshua 's answer since he put a lot of useful information.

Comment: Thanks @HDox. Could I ask you where you put the serve{...} code?

Comment: It is a server block in my web server configure which is NGINX.

Comment: Ok. I'm on Heroku so not sure I have access to that file. I will have to ask them about that.

Comment: This solution only works if you are using nginx and Rails 3.1+.

Comment: I just read @agilehoshua's answer and I would say that it does seem be very deserving with all of the details.  I appreciate your assistance as well as it put me on the right path to fix my issue combined with his

Comment: I'd be more than happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 defaults to a 302 redirect (temporary).  You can try changing it to a 301 (permanent) redirect and see if Google like that better:

```
redirect_to("https://#{request.host}#{request.request_uri}", :status => 301) unless request.ssl?
```

or equivalently:

```
redirect_to("https://#{request.host}#{request.request_uri}", :status => :moved_permanently) unless request.ssl?
```

both code snipets do the exact same thing